# libgdx FileNotFoundException on android device

Tags: java, android, xml, libgdx

I have xml file which I need to read to load level. This file is located in assets folder. 
When I run on desctop machine everything is alright. But on Android device I get FileNotFoundException when try to parse this file. 
Here is code of reading method

```
 public void readLevels() {

    this.levelList = new ArrayList<Level>();
    FileHandle handle = Gdx.files.internal("lvl/levels.xml");


    try {
        File fXmlFile =  handle.file();
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        try {
            Document document = documentBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

            document.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("level");

            Level level;

            for (int iterator = 0; iterator < nodeList.getLength(); iterator++) {
                Node node = nodeList.item(iterator);
                Element element = (Element) node;

                String levelName = element.getAttribute("name");
                int levelNumber = Integer.parseInt(element.getAttribute("order"));

                NodeList ballList = element.getElementsByTagName("ball");

                List<Ball> levelBallList = new ArrayList<Ball>();
                Ball ball;

                for (int iter = 0; iter < ballList.getLength(); iter++) {
                    Element ballIn = (Element) ballList.item(iter);

                    NodeList positionX = ballIn.getElementsByTagName("position-x");
                    NodeList positionY = ballIn.getElementsByTagName("position-y");

                    int x = Integer.parseInt(positionX.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
                    int y = Integer.parseInt(positionY.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());

                    ball = new Ball(new Vector2(y, x), ballTextures[generateImage()]);
                    levelBallList.add(ball);
                }

                level = new Level(levelName, levelNumber, levelBallList);
                this.levelList.add(level);
            }

        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your file name. Android is case sensitive.

Comment: Check if there are caps characters. Desktop is case-insensitive while the android is case-sensitive.

Comment: They are identical

Comment: I found solution!  We get handle as it was:                                    FileHandle handle = Gdx.files.internal("lvl/levels.xml");                              And then write next:                                                              Document document = documentBuilder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(handle.readBytes()));